# Is there a wallpaper changer for Linux like 500 Firepaper for Android?

Tags: linux, android, desktop-customization

[500 Firepaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.firepaper.fivehundredpx) is a wonderful Android app that displays the latest images from [500px](http://500px.com) as your wallpaper, depending on which categories you choose to display. Is there something similar for Linux desktops? I know there are some wallpaper changers, but they require you to have the images stored locally. I really want something that downloads from 500px specifically, as the photography on there is beautiful.

Comment: You can create a script to do this.

Comment: Please move this to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/